# c# How to use Contains() and ignore lower & upper case? vs 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, contains

I am using this code:

```
if (tweet.FullText.ToLower().Contains(hashtag.ToLower()))
```

To check if the tweet contain a certain hashtag.
Is there a better way check it without the ToLower() on both sided? Anyway to make the Contains ignore the lower & upper case differences?

Thx

Comment: `if (tweet.FullText.IndexOf(hashtag, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`

Comment: Thank you :) this is perfect!